# Как изменить файл разметки для одного фрагмента?

Tags: android, android-fragment

имеется класс фрагмента, выполняющий некоторый код, никак не могу найти, как поменять файл разметки для него. На практике в настройках просто выбираю разное расположение элементов и хочу разную разметку для них подгружать.

Comment: Вы фрагмент создавали автоматически? Посмотрите в методе `onCreateView` в `inflate` указывается разметка, которая подгружается.

Comment: @Jarvis_J да в `onCreate` разметка подгружается, но потом если я зайду в настройки и изменю файл разметки в `onResume` прописать `View fragment = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);` уже не получается

Comment: вам надо динамически разметку подгружать?

Comment: да, захожу в настройки, меняю разметку и, возвращаясь во фрагмент, в `onResume` переключаю разметку в зависимости от выбранного в настройках значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отвечать на вопрос, как он поставлен:

Попробуйте в качестве разметки использовать пустой `FrameLayout`(например) и создайте во фрагменте функцию:

```
void changeLayout(int yourLayout) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(yourLayout, null);
    try {
        ((FrameLayout) getView()).removeAllViews(); 
        ((FrameLayout) getView()).addView(v)
    } catch (NullPointerExeption ignored){}
}
```

или, чтобы избегать `NullPointerExeption`, в `onCreateView` определяйте View в глобальную переменную `myFragmetView` (ваш `FrameLayout`)

Но вообще, чтобы избежать возможных ошибок (а со сменой разметки=всех вью, их может быть очень много), мне кажется лучше создавать заново фрагмент, передавая туда id разметки. Хотя я не знаю ваш функционал и задачи :)

Comment: спасибо! это точно нужно.